# SMTP connection is dying after first invalid email using libcurl. Is this a "feature" or am I messing something up?

Tags: c, curl, smtp, libcurl

I'm trying to feed libcurl a long list of emails (some of which end up being non-existent). If there are any invalid emails, the entire script dies.

I can reconnect to the SMTP server for each email address (which does process correctly), but that's just stupidly inefficient.

My relevant code is as follows:

```
// necessary simple curl setup completed above
// assume all referenced variables have been initialized

// init cURL server connection
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, SMTPSERVER);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, MAILFROM);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, stdout);

char tmp[EMAIL_STR_LEN+3] = {0}; tmp[0] = '<';
while( fgets(&tmp[1], EMAIL_STR_LEN+1, emails) ){
        // '>' overwrites '\0' from fgets()
        tmp[EMAIL_STR_LEN-1] = '>';

        strncpy(current->email, tmp, EMAIL_STR_LEN+3);

        // malloc next link
        current->next = initemail();
        current = current->next;

        // remove \n\0 from stream
        fseek(emails, 2, SEEK_CUR);
}
fclose(emails);

current = head;
while(current){
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, (const char *) current->email);
        current = current->next;
}

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);
curl_easy_perform(curl);

// clean up stuff
```

Doing the above, but moving `curl_easy_perform` to be called on a one-email recipient, then NULLing the variable and processing the next email works. Only problem is that libcurl reconnects to SMTP server each time, adding massive overhead to the processing.

I found this "feature" mentioned somewhere in an email thread, but it was a pretty dated response. I was wondering if there is a good way to get around this or if I'm just doing something stupid. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know libcurl that well, but your fseek stinks -- fgets will include the newline in tmp[] and jump it automagically from the stream, while '\0' is appended to the string **anyway**, it's not in the stream unless you put it there.

Comment: @loreb, I would disagree that it "stinks," but you're right. The same could would be achieved by just overwriting the \n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're experiencing the [KNOWN_BUG](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/knownbugs.html) #79:

> SMTP. When sending data to multiple recipients, curl will abort and return   failure if one of the recipients indicate failure (on the
>   "RCPT TO"   command). Ordinary mail programs would proceed and still
>   send to the ones   that can receive data. This is subject for change
>   in the future.   http://curl.haxx.se/bug/view.cgi?id=3438362

Feel free to help us get a fix done!

Comment: Thanks, @DanielStenberg. I'll take a look at the code and see if it's something I can handle then.